# Create Index by population ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

New to MongoDB, and I am trying to categorise populations of cities and counties based on their population. A sample of the data would be as follows:

```
{ "_id" : "D", "name" : "Dar-e-salaam", "pop" : 212253 }
{ "_id" : "WF", "name" : "Westfalia", "pop" : 50257}
{ "_id" : "G", "name" : "Gabon", "pop" : 369536 }
{ "_id" : "M", "name" : "Montgomery", "pop" : 102585 }
{ "_id" : "LA", "name" : "Los Angeles", "pop" : 38562 }
```

I've used this code to get me the following table:

```
db.project.find({pop:{$gt: 0}}, {name:1})

{ "_id" : "LA", "name" : "Los Angeles" }
{ "_id" : "WF", "name" : "Westfalia" }
{ "_id" : "M", "name" : "Montgomery" }
{ "_id" : "G", "name" : "Gabon" }
{ "_id" : "D", "name" : "Dar-e-salaam" }
```

What I am trying to get would be as follows:

```
{ "_id" : "S", "Locations" : ["Los Angeles"] }
{ "_id" : "M", "Locations" : ["Westfalia"] }
{ "_id" : "L", "Locations" : ["Montgomery", "Gabon"] }
{ "_id" : "V", "Locations" : ["Dar-e-salaam"] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). First, use `$project` with `$switch` to output a size of S, M, L, or V based on the population. Then, use `$group` and `$push` to group the documents by size and gather the location names in an array.

```
db.project.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    name: 1, 
    size: { 
      $switch: {
        branches: [
          {
            case: { $lt : [ "$pop", 50000 ] },
            then: "S"
          },
          {
            case: { $and : [ { $gte : [ "$pop", 50000 ] },
                             { $lt : [ "$pop", 100000 ] } ] },
            then: "M"
          },
          {
            case: { $and : [ { $gte : [ "$pop", 100000 ] },
                             { $lt : [ "$pop", 200000 ] } ] },
            then: "L"
          },
          {
            case: { $gte : [ "$pop", 200000 ] },
            then: "V"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$size",
    Locations: { $push : "$name" }
  }
}])
```